# lenght of an inner lists in a nested list

Tags: python, list, nested-lists

How can I find out the len of my inner lists in a nested list like this:

```
A = [[1, ,4, 8], [8, 6, 2, 0], [0], [6 ,4 ,9]]
```

I want to get some output like this

```
3
4
1
3
```

Answer (score 1):

With a list comprehension.

```
>>> A = [[1, 4, 8], [8, 6, 2, 0], [0], [6, 4 ,9]]
>>> lengths = [len(l) for l in A]
[3, 4, 1, 3]
```